# Write the given product of cycles as one permutation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Could I please have help on the following question.

Write the given product of cycles as one permutation:
$$\beta = (1483)(12765)(34687).$$

Could someone please explain how I would approach this? With each and every single step?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Write down (1 and see where 1 goes under the permutation. Then write down that number next to the 1, and see where it goes. Continue as such until you are back at 1. Don't write down 1 again, but write down a right bracket ). Repeat this procedure, starting not with 1 but with the smallest number you haven't yet written down. Stop when all numbers are written.

Answer (score 0):

Do the product **from right to left** (this is *the usual* convention. Very few authors do it the other way. Check this), and see to what number each element is sent. Beginning from lower to higher:

$$\beta=(127)(386)(45)$$

For example, beginning with $\;7\;$ from the right: $\;7\to3\to1\;$ , so in the final result $\;7\;$ must be mapped to $\;1\;$, as it is, and etc.

Comment: I always hated the right to left convention there, I know it is from the $\circ$ convention but it just left a bad taste in my mouth. When I had an exam my teacher said "Do which ever you want"

Comment: @ZelosMalum The convention may be a little odd at first, but it is the only correct thing to do since that's the way most of us all **compose** functions: from right to left. In $\;f\circ  g(x)\;$ , we first *apply* $\;g\;$ and thereafter $\;f\;$ . The only way doing product of permutations from left to right in a logical, sound way is if we accept the almost completely anachronic notation *from algebra* $\;(x)f\;$ or $\;xf\;$ , to denote what we now write as $\;fx\;$ or $\;f(x)\;$ . My algebra teacher was one of the last ones to insist on this. He passed away in 1996...